Min-Cut algorithms for C# QuickGraph
I have an Undirected unweighted Graph with Nodes and Edges. I need to find a set/list of all possible minimal cuts of the graph between given Source Node and Target Node (A cut is a set of edges, which, in case of removal, divide graph into 2 smaller graphs that do not intersect). I have found quite a few articles an abstract about algorithms that can complete this task, however their description is either too complex or too vague. I have found some basic descriptions of Karger's, min S-T cut, or Stoer-Wagner algorithm, but I don't quite understand what the cut is supposed to be inside the algorithm.
I am using C# QuickGraph for this task and have decided to write my own recursive algorithm, but it's not working as intended.
public class GraphHandler
{
    public UndirectedGraph<Node, Edge<Node>> Graph { get; private set; }
    private readonly List<List<Edge<Node>>> MinPaths = new();
    private readonly List<List<Edge<Node>>> MinCuts = new();
    private UndirectedDepthFirstSearchAlgorithm<Node, Edge<Node>> Algorithm;
    private UndirectedVertexPredecessorRecorderObserver<Node, Edge<Node>> Observer;

    public GraphHandler(UndirectedGraph<Node, Edge<Node>> graph)
    {
        Graph = graph;
    }

    public List<List<Edge<Node>>> AllMinCuts(Node Source, Node Target)
    {
        MinCuts.Clear();
        FindMinCuts(Graph.Clone(), Source, Target, new List<Edge<Node>>());
        var Cuts = MinCuts.OrderBy(Cut => Cut.Count).ToArray();
        var OtherCuts = MinCuts.ToArray();
        foreach (List<Edge<Node>> Cut in Cuts)
        {
            foreach(List<Edge<Node>> OtherCut in OtherCuts)
            {
                // If a cut isn't the same, and contains all edges of a small cut
                // Delete this cut form the list
                if (!Cut.Equals(OtherCut) && Cut.All(Edge => OtherCut.Contains(Edge)))
                {
                    MinCuts.Remove(OtherCut);
                }
            }
        }
        return MinCuts;
    }

    private void FindMinCuts(UndirectedGraph<Node, Edge<Node>> graph, Node Source, Node Target, List<Edge<Node>> Cut)
    {
        Algorithm = new(graph);
        Observer = new();
        Observer.Attach(Algorithm);
        Algorithm.Compute(Source);
        if (!Observer.TryGetPath(Target, out _))
        {
            MinCuts.Add(new List<Edge<Node>> (Cut));
            return;
        }
        var Edges = graph.Edges.ToArray();
        foreach (Edge<Node> edge in Edges)
        {
            if (!Cut.Contains(edge))
            {
                Cut.Add(edge);
                graph.RemoveEdge(edge);
                FindMinCuts(graph, Source, Target, Cut);
                graph.AddEdge(edge);
            }
        }
    }
}

What is more, this code will most likely end up in overflow exception with too many verices and is very uneffective, but I don't quite understand the alternatives.

By the way, desciption of all minimum or minimal cuts in my task - are the shortest possible cuts, any of which is a subset for any other bigger cut.

Overflow exception means your recursion is not terminating properly, and just going on forever

I am sure, that you can exceed your stack capacity with complex graphs with more than 20 nodes

I have found some interesting algorithms for finding all different combinations of cuts in a graph. Specifically - Stoer-Wagner's (and maybe Karger's). This algorithm is built in similiar fashion to Breadth-First-Search, except for the recursion, which is instead replaced with Queue and 'while' loop. With such an approach, I can find all possible cuts in different cutting ways. It also requires a "Set" or at least an "Add" function, that will dismiss all duplicate cuts.
Here is the Code:
public class GraphHandler
{
    public UndirectedGraph<Node, GraphEdge> Graph { get; private set; }
    private List<List<GraphEdge>> MinCuts;

    public GraphHandler(UndirectedGraph<Node, GraphEdge> graph)
    {
        Graph = graph;
    }
    public List<List<GraphEdge>> AllMinCuts(Node Source, Node Target)
    {
        MinCuts = new();
        Queue<List<Node>> Queue = new();
        
        List<Node> CurrentSet = new() { Source };
        List<GraphEdge> CurrentCut = new();
        Queue.Enqueue(CurrentSet);
        while (Queue.Count != 0)
        {
            CurrentSet = Queue.Dequeue();
            CurrentCut = new();
            foreach (Node Node in CurrentSet)
            {
                CurrentCut.AddRange(Graph.AdjacentEdges(Node).Where(Edge => !(CurrentSet.Contains(Edge.Source) && CurrentSet.Contains(Edge.Target))));
            }
            MinCuts.AddUnique(CurrentCut);
            if (Graph.Vertices.Count() - CurrentSet.Count >= 2)
            {
                List<GraphEdge> CutWithoutTarget = CurrentCut.Where(Edge => Edge.Source != Target && Edge.Target != Target).ToList();
                foreach (GraphEdge EveryEdge in CutWithoutTarget)
                {
                    List<Node> New = new(CurrentSet);
                    if (CurrentSet.Contains(EveryEdge.Source))
                    {
                        if (!CurrentSet.Contains(EveryEdge.Target))
                        {
                            New.Add(EveryEdge.Target);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        New.Add(EveryEdge.Source);
                    }
                    Queue.Enqueue(New);
                }
            }
        }
        return MinCuts;
    }
}

public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static void AddUnique<T>(this List<List<T>> list, List<T> item)
    {
        if (list.All(innerList => !innerList.All(obj => item.Contains(obj, EqualityComparer<T>.Default))))
        {
            list.Add(item);
        }
    }
}

